# Pine script : how to refer custom indictor in Scanner or strategy

Tags: pine-script

( disclaimer: I am a novice in the pine-script, and still getting hold of it )

I am using custom indicator "SSL Hybrid" - which I am trying to use in the strategy, same as any inbuilt indicator
like RSI e.g.`   rsi  = rsi(close, 14) // Value

when I refer to SSLHybrid ( which is already on the chart ) - I am getting the below error.

x = SSLHybrid(14,1)
Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 9: Could not find function or function reference 'SSLHybrid'.

Can someone, please give me pointers - stuck on this for a while?

Comment: please provide code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in functions is not the same as user functions. You cannot use third party script in this way (except [libraries](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Libraries.html#libraries)).
a) You would need to copy existing code and adapt it for your strategy.

or
b) You can do something like this:
https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000474048

or
c) access another script plots from your strategy by using `input.source` function:
[image]